# Bitbucket pipeline docker image tag changed to image digest during run?

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines

We've started to encounter an error during our bitbucket pipeline builds and are usual troubleshooter is on leave for the next few weeks!!!

We're been trying to figure out whats happened as there havnt been any code changes to the repo but our pipeline builds are now failing.

The difference between a working build and failing build seems to be with the docker image. (which also hasnt changed since last year)

Previously, the build step output would end wih the below

```
.....
Artifact "node_modules/**": Downloading
Artifact "node_modules/**": Downloaded 158.4 MiB in 2 seconds
Artifact "node_modules/**": Extracting
Artifact "node_modules/**": Extracted in 7 seconds
Artifact "package.json": Downloading
Artifact "package.json": Downloaded 1.6 KiB in 0 seconds
Artifact "package.json": Extracting
Artifact "package.json": Extracted in 0 seconds
```

And it would switch over to the next step but now, its changed to..

```
Artifact "node_modules/**": Downloading
Artifact "node_modules/**": Downloaded 158.4 MiB in 2 seconds
Artifact "node_modules/**": Extracting
Artifact "node_modules/**": Extracted in 7 seconds
Artifact "package.json": Downloading
Artifact "package.json": Downloaded 1.6 KiB in 0 seconds
Artifact "package.json": Extracting
Artifact "package.json": Extracted in 0 seconds
Images used:
    build : docker-pullable://dtr/docker-image/server@sha256:1261f2df0f4..............
```

No where do we specify a docker image with the image digest, we have a docker image with the tag listed within our `pipebucket-pipeline.yml` file but not the digest. Whats odd is that in previous successful builds the `images used` line doesnt appear any where in the build step output.

Why would this change suddently? where is the image digest being specified and whats causing it now to appear as part of the build step??